# Trying to find docker-compose remote API

Tags: api, docker, docker-compose

Can I run docker-compose thru docker deamon remote socket?
I wasnt able to find anything on Engine AIP https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#310-tasks

In case docker does not support that, are you aware of any docker-compose remote API?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker compose is just a utility that delegates the commands to the Docker daemon. Docker compose does not have a client sever architecture like Docker. It is only a client tool.

Thus there are no docker-compose apis. You can achieve everything by talking directly to the docker daemonexposed api.